# Forcing Child class to implement deep-copy methods

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a parent class "Parent" which requires a template parameter K for the data type it operates on. For the child implementations, I'd like to force these to implement a custom "deepcopy" method.

An example use of the deepcopy method is given by the "Runner" class, which essentially holds a master copy of a given Child implementation. Note that in a real-world example, the Runner type would have multiple threads accessing and mutating the "master" field simultaneously while holding a lock, hence the need for deep-copies of the master type.

I've currently solved this as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template<typename T, typename K>
class Parent{
public:
    virtual void mutate_state(std::vector<K> &data)=0;
    T deepcopy(){
        T res;
        res = static_cast<T&>(*this);
        return res;
    }
};


// some example implementation of Base<T, K>
class Child : public Parent<Child, int>{
private:
    std::vector<int> all_elements;
    int state;
public:
    void mutate_state(std::vector<int> &data) override{
        // do something with data & cfg
        all_elements.insert(all_elements.end(), data.begin(), data.end());
        state++;
        std::cout<<"Called A, state is: "<<state<<std::endl;
    }
    Child(Child &child) {
        std::cout<<"call custom child copy constructor"<<std::endl;
        state = child.state;
    }
    Child& operator=(Child other)
    {
        std::cout<<"call custom child copy assignment"<<std::endl;
        std::swap(state, other.state);
        return *this;
    }
    Child(): state(0){};
};


// an example class mutating the Child
template<typename T, typename K>
class Runner {
private:

    // master Child instance
    T master;
    
public:
    explicit Runner(T child_impl) : master(child_impl) {}

    T get_master_deepcopy() {
        return master.deepcopy();
    }

    void update_master_model(T new_master) {
        master = new_master;
    }

    void update(std::vector<int> &data){
        T temp_deepcopy = get_master_deepcopy();
        temp_deepcopy.mutate_state(data);
        master = temp_deepcopy;
    }
};



int main() {
    Child base_impl;

    // not nice: I have to keep specifying template type K=int although its already been defined in the child implementation
    Runner<Child, int> runner(base_impl);

    std::vector<int> some_data;
    runner.update(some_data);
}
```

However, my implementation feels cumbersome.

- There is currently no mechanism to "force" an implementation of custom copy operators in a child implementation. If they are forgotten, a child implementation which uses complex dynamically allocated types may only lead to shallow copy which I want to strictly avoid.
- My Runner is unaware of the true type of T which should be restricted to inherit from the class Parent<T, K>
- Also, I dislike the need to repeatedly declare the type of template parameter K
  both in the implementation of Child as well when instantiating the "Runner" type. Is there a way to extract the template type K from the already defined Child class when instantiating the "Runner" type?

How can I improve this approach?

Comment: what do you mean with "Runner is unaware of the true type of T" ? `Runner` is `template<typename T, typename K> class Runner` it *knows* `T`.

Comment: the way to force a child class to implement a method is to make it pure virtual in the base, as you already did with `mutate_state`

Comment: please focus on one question

Comment: It's kind of a grey area, but it may be better on [codereview.se]. You have a working implementation that you would like to improve from code style perspective. Although if you split the question onto 3 separate ones, it would be valid here as well.

Comment: you may want to read about [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to better frame your approach

Comment: each of your bullets could make a seperate individual question.

Comment: On a side note: `mutate_state` doesn'tn have to be virtual. You can save yourself a vtable loopup by delegating CRTP-style to the templated derived class, just like you do in `Parent::deepcopy`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The code needs to be actual code from a project, it appears that the Parent Class and the Runner class are not the actual names of the classes.